# Explanation of linux shell access via backpipes?

Tags: linux, netcat

I have been looking at different ways to gain shell access to a Linux machine and came across [this](https://www.lanmaster53.com/2011/05/7-linux-shells-using-built-in-tools/) article.

Under point #2, there is an slightly different way of using netcat to gain shell. here it is:

[image]

According to man pages,

> The system call mknod() creates a filesystem node (file, device,
>   special file, or named pipe) named pathname, with attributes specified
>   by mode and dev.

But I still don't understand what is happening and couldn't find an explanation for it online. Can someone please help explain the command in the Target console?

Many thanks!

Comment: please do not post images of text

Comment: How mknod works is not really a security question but a Linux question. Everything you need to understand about how to use it for a remote shell is all in your question. If you do not understand the concepts or terms used in relation to mknod, FIFO, or pipes, then you might need to ask at SuperUser or Unix StackExchange.

Comment: If it helps, the name `backpipe` is just arbitrary text and not a configuration option. It could just as easily be named `foobar`. the rest of the command is just run-of-the-mill bash piping

Comment: Thank you @schroeder, i shall approach one of the other forums. :)